# Anything wrong with this BDD spec?

Tags: google-app-engine, bdd

I'm new to Behavior Driven Design (BDD) so I'd like feedback on whether I've applied it correctly.

The feature I'm about to develop exports a list of Twitter handles ("authors") from a data repository and sends it as a CSV email attachment to the requestor.  The data repository is Google App Engine's data store.

Reviewing Dan North's main description of Behavior Driven Testing: http://dannorth.net/introducing-bdd/, here is how I would specify my test:

**Title: Analyst exports authors**

*As* an analyst

*I want* to export authors

*So* I can analyze what they talk about in another system.

***Scenario 1: Segment contains authors and export can be sent***

*Given* the segment contains authors

*And* the user has provided their email address in their user profile

*When* the user clicks export for that segment

*Then* ensure the user receives the authors as a CSV attachment to an email.

***Scenario 2: Segment contains authors but export can't be sent***

*Given* the segment contains authors

*And* the user has not provided their email address in their user profile

*When* the user clicks export for that segment

*Then* remind the user to set their email address in their user profile first.

***Scenario 3: Segment contains no authors***

*Given* the segment contains no authors

*When* the user clicks export for that segment

*Then* prevent the user from clicking the export button

*And* display a message that the segment has no authors to export.

A few questions:

1. What other scenarios should I consider or have I scoped this story too narrowly?
2. Should Scenario 3 be part of a different story?  Dan North says the scenarios should share the same event.  However, the user experience would probably be such that the user could not click the export button because it's disabled.  Should I have written the event differently so that it would have fit all scenarios, for example, "*When* the user goes to export the segment".
3. Is there anything else that would make this a better BDD test?
4. Any tips for how to implement a test like that depends on other systems such as the Google App Engine data store and email systems?  Should I stub the data store?  How do I test that an email attachment is received?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**One event per story?**

We'd probably say these days that the scenarios should be about the same capability; in this case, the capability to export authors via email. Most of them will have an event that performs the export, but anything else related to that capability belongs with it too.

I normally make the default case successful, i.e.:

> When the user exports the segment

And use *tries* for when it fails:

> When the user tries to export the segment

However, in the case that the export button is disabled, there's probably something else going on. What's the trigger for the user seeing that message that there are no authors? It would probably be something like:

> Given there are no authors for a segment
>   When the user views that segment
>   Then they should be told that there are no authors for that segment.

**How could you improve the scenarios?**

Avoid mixing the UI domain in with your Twitter app domain. Talk about "when a user exports that segment" rather than the button-click. Perhaps one day it will be a drag-and-drop on a touch-screen, rather than a button-click. If perhaps you decide that way works better, and today is the day, you can change it and your scenarios will still be valid. Apart from the button-click your scenarios are really good; better than average, certainly.

In BDD we try to avoid using the word "test" unless we're really talking about testing, and these are just scenarios, or examples, which happen to provide tests as a nice by-product. Call them examples or scenarios and you'll find it easier to talk to business people about it, and to think of more examples yourself. I've also written [a blog post on a couple of patterns I use](http://lizkeogh.com/2011/09/22/conversational-patterns-in-bdd/) for spotting missing scenarios, which might help you. Testers are really good at spotting these, so bring one into the conversation if you can. If you can't, try and find another analyst or business expert to put that hat on.

**How many scenarios are in a story?**

A story is just a slice through a feature for faster feedback, and the number of scenarios you might have in it is largely arbitrary and dependent on how easy the team find these things to code. Focus on getting feedback from a stakeholder at the end of a sprint, and make the stories small enough that you can get that feedback internally quickly, and large enough that you can show the stakeholders something interesting. I know teams who code entire features (and are happy showcasing part-way through), and teams who make each scenario a separate story, and teams who do something in between (all the successful exports, then all the edge-cases, for instance). All these approaches are valid.

**How to include dependent systems?**

You can either mock these out (by writing your own stub system, or by using a mocking framework or for those unlucky souls using SOAP, SOAP UI, etc.) or you can use the real system. In your case, I'd be tempted to deploy to a test version of the real system, and set up a test email domain to which I could send the emails (or stub that out, as above). There are lots of ways to access email inboxes via APIs, or you could always automatically export them to a file or database, etc.

Do whatever allows you to get fast feedback on your code, remembering that any system you don't automatically test will have to be manually verified, that things like email gateways are unlikely to change (and therefore unlikely to have bugs), and that BDD is not a substitute for manually testing at least once anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The scenarios you've given do two things

1. Explore the happy path: the authors can be exported
2. Start exploring sad paths: the authors can't be exported for various reasons

In general I would concentrate on making the happy path as clean and simple as possible, before dealing with sad paths, otherwise you end up doing to much at once.

Currently you are doing to much at once and you have a number of anomalies in your scenarios. Lets look at a couple of them:

1. You've talked about 'segment' in your scenarios, but I have no idea what a segment is and why it should have authors. It sounds like its an implementation detail, and doesn't belong.
2. You've specifically said that the report should be a csv sent to an email addresses. Why are you choosing this mechanism? Wouldn't it be easier to just let the analyst download the CSV?

What I'd suggest is that you examine the happy path and go through the language with a fine toothed comb trying to remove all these sorts of anomalies, so you can get to the essence of the problem. This might end up being as simple as

```
Given there are some authors
When I ask for an export of authors
Then I should get a list of authors
```

From this you can then add stuff specific to your context. Lets say that only analysts can do this. Then we might get

```
Given I am an analyst
And their are some authors
When ...
```